Lebesgue measure generating set
In my cource of measure theory, Lebesgue measure were built starting with measure on semiring $S\subset 2^X$, after we defined outer measure for each $A\in2^X$ by $\inf\{ \sum{m[B] : A\subset \cup B , B \subset S} \}$, defined what are Lesbegue measurable sets, and prooved that they form $\sigma$-algebra. What confuse me here - is why we start this construction with semiring. Because:

As i undestood from here and here, what we realy need to define $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets - is countably subadditive outer measure. Proof, that $\inf\{ \sum{m[B] : A\subset \cup B , B \subset S} \}$ is countably subadditive - uses only that $S$ is cover of $X$ (proof given with geometric progression)

In wikipedia Lebesgue measure for $ℝ$ constructed from topology of $ℝ$, and only common thing between topology and semiring with $E$ (biggets set), is that both of them are covers, again.

In this answer pointed that any system of sets could be used to generate minimal $\sigma$-algebra.


So, my question is - can we use any cover to generate Lebesgue measure on measurable sets of $2^X$, and Lebesgue measure generated by topology/semiring - are just cases of it? If not, how do we generalize semiring and topology in this perspective?
Finally, i understand all theorems about semirings in my cource, but still this structure seems to me very strange, i just dont feel it. I would appreciate if you would explain me intuition behind it, may be formulate it in more abstract terms. My guess - outer measure, generated by semiring, fulfills some criterias, but which ones?

The structure if semi-ring is basically adopted from the property if intervals of the form $(a,b]$, $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. The difference of two such intervals is the (finite) union of intervals of the same form. That is all one needs to construct the Lebesgue measure. The rest is abstraction, that is all one needs is semi-rings and some continuity property of the "initial" measure defined on it.
